# how to convert this SQL Server query into Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

How to convert below Sql Server query into Oracle

```
SELECT
    totalRecords = (SELECT
                        COUNT(*) 
                    FROM
                        Finance
    )
    ,
    positiveAmt = SUM(positiveAmount),
    negativeAmt = SUM(negativeAmount) 
FROM
    Finance
```

Comment: May I know the reason for negative vote.

Comment: Probably because you didn't even try to do it yourself. We aren't a code conversion service.

Comment: @mmmmmpie I tried lot many options before posting here. Infact, I used online sql translators like sqlines. It was a tricky conversion as can be seen from below answers and comments. So, it's a wrong assumption that I have not tried before posting. This is the first time I got negative vote for my question.

Comment: You asked, I answered. Thats why you got negative votes.

Comment: So the negative vote is based on your wrong assumptions.

Comment: I didn't down vote you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`negativeAmt = SUM(negativeAmount)` is Microsoft's non-standard way of defining a column alias.

In Oracle (and pretty much every other DBMS) a column alias is written *after* the column expression that should be aliased, not in front of it.

So your query becomes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalRecords,
       SUM(positiveAmount) as positiveAmt, 
       SUM(negativeAmount) as negativeAmt
FROM Finance
```

The `AS` keyword is optional, but I recommend using it to make things clearer.

Oracle SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f7da/1
SQL Server fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7f7da/1

Comment: I am getting below error on running this: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Comment: @VikasSharma: I'm pretty sure the original statement as shown would have produced the same error in SQL Server. you are clearly not showing us everything

Comment: @VikasSharma: Interesting, I would not have thought that SQL Server allows that. But you can replace the sub-select with a simple `count(*)`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*), sum(positiveAmount), sum(negativeAmount)
  into totalRecords, positiveAmt, negativeAmt
  from Finance;
```

Comment: I am getting below error on running this: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: It maybe means that you tried to execute this as single SQL statement. Oracle supports variables only in PL/SQL, so this statement can be executing into PL/SQL only.

Comment: So, is it not possible using sql? As, I am calling the sql from my java code.

Comment: @SanderstheSoftwarer: those aren't variables in SQL Server. Those are column aliases

Comment: As I remember, SQL Server uses the same statement into T-SQL as variable assignment statement. Anyway, Vikas, please describe what you expect to get using this statement?

Comment: Variables would be prefixed with `@`, e.g. `@totalRecords`